# search and delete a node from linked list

Tags: c, dictionary, linked-list

I am writing a simple dictionary program using linked list. I want to search a word in the dictionary and delete it. I've wrote the code, but I think It's more time consuming as I'm running the loop two times, 1st to search the node and note down the position and 2nd to delete it.

```
struct node{
    char word[20];
    char meaning[5][100];
    struct node *next;
};

void del(struct node *head, char *word)
{
  int found = 0, position = 0, i;
  struct node *temp = head;
  while(temp != NULL)
  {
    if(strcmp(temp->word, word) == 0)
    {
        found = 1;
        break;
    }
    temp = temp->next;
    position++;
  }
  if(found == 1)
  {
      temp = head;
      if(position == 0)
      {
          head = temp->next;
          free(temp);
      }
      for(i = 0; i < position-1; i++)
          temp = temp->next;
      struct node *temp2 = temp->next;
      temp->next = temp2->next;
      free(temp2);
      printf("Word deleted..\n");
  }
  else printf("Word not found!\n");
}
```

is there any alternate way to optimize the program?

Comment: When you run the search loop, also temporarily store the parent of the current node you are checking. When you find the node you want to remove, just set its parent's next pointer, to the node about to be removed next and then delete the node.

Comment: how do I get the previous node address??

Comment: you need to delete the word as soon as you find it.

Comment: @surjit When going through the list, at *the end* of each step store the current node into a variable. In the *next step* you can use that variable because it contains the *previous node*. When you have done that, you can change your program to only use one loop because you have the previous node available, so you can delete the node.

Comment: I'm confusing while resetting the links after deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to merge the two cycles together like this, here's a code example.

```
struct node{
    char word[20];
    char meaning[5][100];
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *del(struct node *head, char *word)
{int found = 0, position = 0, i;
  struct node *temp = head;
  struct node *prev = NULL;
  /*You should avoid breaks because they decrease legibility*/
  while(temp != NULL)
  {

    if(strcmp(temp->word, word) == 0)
    {
        if(prev == NULL){ /*If the node is the head*/
            head = head->next;
            free(temp);
            return head;
        }else{
            prev->next = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            return head;
        }
    }
    prev = temp;
    temp = temp->next;
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it should be `prev->next = temp->next` instead of `prev = temp->next`

Comment: the code isn't removing the node. rather it's changing the word with some garbage value and the meaning remains the same..

Comment: before using `del()` the list had `word = go`, `meaning = something`. After using `del()` list shows `word = x5`, `meaning = something`. It replaced the word with some garbage value I guess

Comment: @surjit as you can read from comments i made a mistake and i edited it. Can you please try this new code now? It works for me, let me know